# Strong's Hebrew: 8328. שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ (shoresh) meaning and use

Tags: hebrew, intertextuality

[Strong's Hebrew: 8328.](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_8328.htm) שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ (shoresh) have used in many verses of the bible, the word is also used in Job 28:9 with relation to the mountain, and also in Job 36:30 with the sea, also with plant and people,שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ is translated as "root". Q: What is the literal meaning of  "שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ"? How do understand it?

> Job 28:9 - “Man puts his hand to the flinty rock and overturns
> mountains by the **roots**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crucial thing to remember at the start, is that Hebrew is not a code for English, nor is it a word substitution.

It is safe to say it means "**roots**" as in plants, and can have that literal meaning of referring to the roots of plants.  And one can also use it in plant-based metaphors. It also can refer to the stump, such as in those tree roots that are above ground. It is used this way (as a continued mixed-metaphor of roots and serpents) in Isaiah 14:29 since those roots and serpents are both long things that crawl upon the ground and annoy the sons of men.

**However**, when English then goes beyond the plant it focuses on the idea of roots giving life such as in the "root cause" or the "root of the problem", which is sort of a weed-like image of needing to make sure to dig up the roots. That  is not how it is used in Biblical Hebrew, in Biblical Hebrew ***it is the roots that hold the plant in place***. It continues to be below and in the ground, but unlike in the English it is not below and hidden but below and firmly supporting the plant (or mountain, or sea above) above.

To use an example not in scripture, we would refer to the tip of the iceberg or the other part. The biblical Hebrew speaker, however, would find no difficulty in calling the other part "שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ".

Comment: For mountains does it just have the sense of the bottom-most part?

Comment: For mountains, I am inclined to say this is referring to the hard rock below the soil below ground level. (Which, may not be literally accurate) I think the metaphor of the oak tree (or the cedar) is intended although at a much bigger level.

Answer (score 1):

In Job 28:9, the word שֶׁרֶשׁ is translated "roots" or "base" or similar.  See below for the BDB entry for this word.

Note the meaning intended here is the "root" of a mountain, meaning its lowest stratum (#3 below).

**APPENDIX - Brown-Driver-Briggs**

שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ noun masculineDeut 29:17 root; — ׳שׁ absolute Deuteronomy 29:17 +, construct Isaiah 11:10 +; suffix שָׁרְשִׁי Job 29:19, etc.; plural construct שָׁרְשֵׁי Job 13:27 (see below) Job 36: suffix שָֽׁרָשָׁיו Amos 2:9 +, שָֽׁרָשֶׁיהָ Ezekiel 17:7 +; —

1 **root of people** under figure of tree, involving firmness, permanence, Amos 2:9; Hosea 9:16; Hosea 14:6; Isaiah 14:30; 2 Kings 19:30 = Isaiah 37:31; — שָׁרְשָׁם Judges 5:14 is probably corrupt, see GFM; — so of person (compare Phoenician, Eshmunazar11 GACookepp. 30, 36) Isaiah 5:24; Malachi 3:19; Job 8:17; Job 18:16; Job 29:19; Proverbs 12:3,12; = stock, family Isaiah 11:1,10; Daniel 11:7, compare (of serpent) Isaiah 14:29; = source or cause Deuteronomy 29:17, דָּבָר ׳שׁ Job 19:28.

2 **literally root** of tree or shrub Jeremiah 17:8 (simile), Ezekiel 31:7 (metaphor of people). Isaiah 53:2 (simile), Job 14:8; Job 30:4; of vine (metaphor of people) Ezekiel 17:6,7,9 (twice in verse); Psalm 80:10 (accusative of congnate meaning with verb with שׁרשׁ Hiph`il).

3 **root**, figurative=lowest stratum, of mountain Job 28:9, of sea Job 36:30= bottom (text strange and dubious: Du רָאשֵׁי הָרִים, with אֵרוֺ in va); of feet, שָׁרְשֵׁי רַגְלַי Job 13:27, i.e. soles Ew Di De Da and others (elsewhere כַּף), Bu place of treading, footholds; Du (arbitrarily) שָׁרְשִׁי, strike out רגלי.

[שֹׁ֫רֶשׁ] noun masculineDan 4:12 root (see Biblical Hebrew); — plural suffix שָׁרְשׁוֺ֫הִי of tree Daniel 4:12; Daniel 4:20; Daniel 4:23.